# RefineryCMS logo in edit mode causes a browser error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

I have a stiuation with the RefineryCMS logo in site edit mode that causes a browser mixed content error.  This is probably not an issue with the out of box RefineryCMS.  I have several web sites that the content is required to be served over an https connection.  So my Refinery sites are being served with https from my server.  Everything seems to be fine except the RefineryCMS logo that appears in the edit bar of the sites. This is the bar that also contains the "Switch to ..." button.  The problem is that the RefineryCMS logo points to the server that has the RefineryCMS information on it using this URL: http://refinerycms.com/images/refinery/logo-site-bar.png.  This url is clearly a standard http request, so when any of these pages displays, the browser displays an error that some content on the page is not being delivered securely.

What I need to do is figure out a way to get the Refinery site to look for its logo on my server, rather than the RefineryCSM server.  I have tested the Refinery server and it doesn't support https so I would get errors if I requested https://refinerycms.com/images/refinery/logo-site-bar.png.  Does anyone know of a way this can be overridden?  I would prefer to keep the Refinery as close to stock as possible, so if there is a standard Refinery way to do this, I would prefer it.  If I need to hack something to get it working, I can do that but prefer not to. This is driving me and my clients crazy because every time they change pages, they get a browser error while editing their sites.

Comment: Was this question not already answered here:

http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms/browse_thread/thread/11ffcc533831e6f7

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for pointing it out.  The answer in that link is what I was looking for.